# How to get python 2.7.3 in virtualenv instead of python 2.7.1?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I have python 2.7.3 install on my mac OS X. 
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

Then I created a virtual environment: 
$ virtualenv 1stVirtualenv
Now the python version is 2.7.1

I searched online and some people suggested using -p option, so I tried this
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 2ndVirtualenv
It is still 2.7.1

I could not find any answers to solve this problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you activate the created environments?

Answer (score 0):

The python files in `/usr/bin` are links to python binaries in `/System/Library/Frameworks/`. Running `/usr/bin/python2.7 --version` will return the system  python's version: 2.7.1. The /usr/bin/pythons are Apple controlled, leave them alone.

Run this to figure out where your 2.7.3 version of Python lives:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Then use whatever path is returned as the argument to virtualenv's p flag:

```
$ virtualenv --distribute -p /usr/local/bin/python ~/virtualenvs/venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
New python executable in virtualenvs/venv/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an quick and easy way to get Python and your virtualenvs up and running quickly:

1. [Install Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
2. Install Python 2.7.3 with `brew install python`
3. `pip install virtualenv`
4. `/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv --distribute ~/virtualenvs/venv`
   -- you'll be using virtualenv so you don't need to update your PATH
5. `source ~/virtualenvs/venv/bin/activate`

I believe that virtualenv defaults to whatever version of python it was installed with. Using Homebrew's Python means less worry about which version points where.

For convenience, you may want to call `source ~/virtualenvs/venv/bin/activate` from your shell's login config (bashrc, profile, etc).